# Antennas Far field radiation pattern

Tags: antenna, electromagnetic, theory, radiation, far-field

I want to understand this Far field graph of an antenna generated in CST, from the picture:

[image: Far field graph]

Is this a good radiation pattern?
If yes, then how?
How to explain the graph?

Comment: Hi there! I'm not following you all the way here, what is your question?

Comment: I wanted to understand this Fairfield graph of the antenna generated in CST. Is this a good radiation pattern? if yes, then how? and how to explain far field field graph?

Comment: Ok, I can tell that English isn't your native language, that's why I ask. I made an proposed edit using your comment as the source and if it is approved, check if you think it's alright, otherwise you can always edit it yourself. Take care now.